# WP-Cron based on array list

Tags: wordpress

I've never used WP Cron in my life and I'm struggling with a task.

I have the following array:

```
$times = array(10:00, 15:00, 21:00);
```

I need to schedule this times so I can call the enable_update()

this is the function:

```
function enable_update(){
 $GLOBALS['cron'] = true;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Something that I tried:

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to add a specific event to be executed on a given time on WP Cron, you may need to use one of the below functions to set it up:

- Single Event: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/
- Recurring Event: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/

You could use those functions to set up the events, and then WP Cron would run them according to the scheduled time.

```php
// Schedule the event to run daily.
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_cron_hook' );
}

// Add the action to be executed daily.
function my_cron_function() {
    // Do whatever you need.
}

add_action( 'my_cron_hook', 'my_cron_function' );
```

Hope that helps!